# JMeter - How to execute list of Http requests and collect results statistics

Tags: jmeter

I need to execute list of Http requests sequentially and collect the results / statistics for each requests. A map holds the request start time as key and the request object as value.

I could done it in three steps:

1. Build a result set using request base details presented in the Oracle tables
2. Iterate the result set.

   2a) Fetch each record, create request object with the details and also build a map with request start time as key and request object as value.

   2b) Form SOAP request XML message using the request object data and add it as a value to the HttpArguement

   2c) Created JMeter test plan, configure JMeter, execute the plan and collect the results

   2d) Calculate the delay time based on the request start time in between the requests and set the running thread to sleep state
3. Finally, the service got terminated after execution of all the records.

Now, I can execute the test successfully. But, I am not sure it is the correct approach. Please check it up and let me know if I am wrong.

Also, now I am getting result summary of individual request as coded. But, I like to get the cumulative statistics after execution of all the requests. How to do so? Please guide me.

The complete code is as follows:

```
// Build the result set [baseReqRecords] of request details from the database

while (baseReqRecords.next()) {
    // Get the request details
    // Get the start time

    long delay = 0;

    if (previousRequestStartTime != null) {
        delay = ((requestStartTime.getTime() - previousRequestStartTime
                .getTime()));
    }

    HTTPSamplerProxy httpSampler = new HTTPSamplerProxy();
    httpSampler.setName("SOAP Request");
    httpSampler.setEnabled(true);
    httpSampler.setPostBodyRaw(true);

    HTTPArgument httpArgument = new HTTPArgument();
    httpArgument.setAlwaysEncoded(false);
    httpArgument.setMetaData("=");

    if (operationsMap.get(reqOperation).equals(
            <<DESIRED_OPERATION>>)) {
        // build the request context object from the request details
        httpArgument.setValue(<<SOAP MESSAGE>>);
    }

    Arguments arguments = new Arguments();
    arguments.addArgument(httpArgument);

    System.out.println("HTTP Argument value: "
            + httpArgument.getValue());

    HeaderManager headerManager = new HeaderManager();
    headerManager.add(new Header("<<SM_USER>>",
            "<<value>>"));
    headerManager.add(new Header("Content-Type",
            "text/xml; charset=utf-8"));
    headerManager
            .add(new Header(
                    "SOAPAction",
                    "<<ACTION_URL>>"));
    headerManager.setName(JMeterUtils
            .getResString("header_manager_title"));
    headerManager.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS,
            HeaderPanel.class.getName());
    headerManager.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS,
            HeaderManager.class.getName());

    System.out.println("Headers: " + headerManager.getHeaders());

    httpSampler.setArguments(arguments);
    httpSampler.setDomain("<<SERVER>>");
    httpSampler.setPort(<<PORT>>);
    httpSampler
            .setPath("<<PATH>>");
    httpSampler.setMethod("POST");
    httpSampler.setName("Sampler");
    httpSampler.setFollowRedirects(true);
    httpSampler.setAutoRedirects(false);
    httpSampler.setUseKeepAlive(true);
    httpSampler.setDoMultipartPost(false);
    httpSampler.setMonitor(false);
    httpSampler.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS,
            HttpTestSampleGui.class.getName());
    httpSampler.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS,
            HTTPSamplerProxy.class.getName());

    LoopController loopController = new LoopController();
    loopController.setEnabled(true);
    loopController.setFirst(true);
    loopController.setContinueForever(false);
    loopController.setLoops(1);
    loopController.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS,
            LoopControlPanel.class.getName());
    loopController.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS,
            LoopController.class.getName());
    loopController.initialize();

    ThreadGroup threadGroup = new ThreadGroup();
    threadGroup.setNumThreads(1);
    threadGroup.setRampUp(1);
    threadGroup.setScheduler(false);
    threadGroup.setSamplerController(loopController);
    threadGroup.setEnabled(true);
    threadGroup.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS,
            ThreadGroupGui.class.getName());
    threadGroup.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS,
            ThreadGroup.class.getName());

    TestPlan testPlan = new TestPlan(
            "Test Plan");
    testPlan.setComment("Service Operations Test Plan");
    testPlan.setFunctionalMode(false);
    testPlan.setSerialized(false);
    testPlan.setUserDefinedVariables((Arguments) new ArgumentsPanel()
            .createTestElement());
    testPlan.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS,
            TestPlanGui.class.getName());
    testPlan.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS,
            TestPlan.class.getName());

    HashTree testPlanTree = new HashTree();

    HashTree samplerTree = new HashTree();
    samplerTree.add(httpSampler, headerManager);

    testPlanTree.add(testPlan);
    HashTree threadGroupHashTree = testPlanTree.add(testPlan,
            threadGroup);
    threadGroupHashTree.add(samplerTree);

    SaveService.saveTree(testPlanTree, new FileOutputStream(
            "jmeter_api.jmx"));

    Summariser summary = null;
    String summariserName = JMeterUtils.getPropDefault(
            "summariser.name", "summary");
    if (summariserName.length() > 0) {
        summary = new Summariser(summariserName);
    }

    String reportFile = "report.jtl";
    ResultCollector logger = new ResultCollector(summary);
    logger.setFilename(reportFile);
    testPlanTree.add(testPlanTree.getArray()[0], logger);

    jmeter.configure(testPlanTree);

    previousRequestStartTime = requestStartTime;
    jmeter.run();

    System.out.println("delay = " + delay);

    Thread.sleep(delay);
}
```

Assume that there are 5 request details records in the result set. The request start time difference is 60 seconds. Now, I have received the following results after execution:

```
summary =      1 in 00:00:01 =    0.9/s Avg:  1002 Min:  1002 Max:  1002 Err:     0 (0.00%)
delay = 0
summary =      1 in 00:00:01 =    1.1/s Avg:   850 Min:   850 Max:   850 Err:     0 (0.00%)
delay = 60000
summary =      1 in 00:00:01 =    1.5/s Avg:   612 Min:   612 Max:   612 Err:     0 (0.00%)
delay = 60000
summary =      1 in 00:00:01 =    1.1/s Avg:   859 Min:   859 Max:   859 Err:     0 (0.00%)
delay = 60000
summary =      1 in 00:00:01 =    1.1/s Avg:   849 Min:   849 Max:   849 Err:     0 (0.00%)
```

Answer (score 0):

The statistics is written into `report.jtl` file, you can open it with the [Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners) of your choice, i.e. [Aggregate Report](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report) and see requests summary. You can also build an [HTML Reporting Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) using that `report.jtl` file like:

```
jmeter -g report.jtl -o /path/to/report/folder
```

I would recommend using different labels for your requests as given they all have `SOAP Request` name it won't be possible to distinguish them in the final report.

Actually you don't even need the Java API, you could use [JDBC Request sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/real-secret-building-database-test-plan-jmeter) to get request data from Oracle and [ForEach Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) to iterate the result set.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri again for your answer.

Comment: I am not going to send any query to database periodically. For example, database update / insert on every sample. Do I really need to use JDBC request sampler here?